# SWT SWT.WRAP in Button

Tags: java, button, layout, checkbox, swt

I want to create a checkbox button with SWT.WRAP. When I resize the window, the text should be wrapped accordingly.

I created a snippet with 2 checkboxes:

1) The text does not wrap

2) The text does wrap but it is not updated when the window is resized

```
public class GridLayoutSample {
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);

private static final String lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ips";

public GridLayoutSample() {

GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
gridLayout.numColumns = 1;
gridLayout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK | SWT.WRAP);
button.setText(lorem);
button.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_FILL));

RowLayout layout = new RowLayout();
Composite row = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
row.setLayout(layout);
createButton(row, lorem, SWT.CHECK | SWT.WRAP);

shell.pack();
shell.open();

while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    display.sleep();
  }
}

display.dispose();
}
public void createButton(Composite parent, String text, int style) {
  RowData layoutData = new RowData();
  layoutData.height = 175;
  layoutData.width = 175;
  Button testButton = new Button(parent, style);
  testButton.setText(text);
  testButton.setLayoutData(layoutData);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  new GridLayoutSample();
}
}
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
Display                     display = new Display();
Shell                       shell   = new Shell(display);

private static final String lorem   = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ips";

public GridLayoutSample()
{
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    Composite row = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    row.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    row.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    createButton(row, lorem, SWT.CHECK | SWT.WRAP);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}

public void createButton(final Composite parent, String text, int style)
{
    final GridData layoutData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    layoutData.widthHint = 175;
    final Button testButton = new Button(parent, style);
    testButton.setText(text);
    testButton.setLayoutData(layoutData);

    parent.getParent().addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            layoutData.widthHint = parent.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).x;
            parent.pack();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new GridLayoutSample();
}
```

---

It will resize the `Button` based on the parent's size.

This is what it looks like after starting:

[image]

And after resizing:

[image]